# Django:Send email after redirect

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

Is there a way to send an email just after 'return redirect'?

views.py

Option 1: Placing 'send_mail' before 'redirect'

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
                formset = TestFormSet(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=project)
                if formset.is_valid():
                    subject = 'Notifications'
                    html_message = "Testing notifications"
                    recipient = ["testingemail@gmail.com"]
                    send_mail(subject, html_message, EMAIL_HOST_USER, [recipient],fail_silently = False)
                    formset.save()
                    return redirect("home")


With Option 1, the email is sent successfully but on the front-end the page has to wait until the email is sent before the redirection takes place.
```

Option 2: Placing 'send_mail' after redirect

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
                formset = TestFormSet(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=project)
                if formset.is_valid():
                    formset.save()
                    return redirect("home")
                    subject = 'Notifications'
                    html_message = "Testing notifications"
                    recipient = ["testingemail@gmail.com"]
                    send_mail(subject, html_message, EMAIL_HOST_USER, [recipient],fail_silently = False)
```

With Option 2, formset is saved but email is not sent.
Is there a way to send the email after the redirection so that the user doesn't wait for the email processing before the page is redirected?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any code after `return` will not run. One approach is to use a task queue like celery and send the email as a background task. You could look at [django-mailer](https://github.com/pinax/django-mailer). The disadvantage of these approaches is that you have an extra system to maintain.

You might see some solutions that send the email in a separate thread, but I would avoid these as they could be fragile.

Comment: The standard django send_mail() actually works. I changed 'EMAIL_HOST_USER' to 'settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER'.My import was incorrect. But i decided to go with celery and it works too.Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: *The standard django send_mail() actually works* - my point is that Option 2 well not work, because code after the return does not run.